# GTK change size WIDGET

Tags: gtk, gtk2, gtk2hs

I have since months a problem in my software (In GTK2). I have a WIDGET (picture.png) which has a certain size. I define the X and Y coordinates of the image and set the size at the beginning to Zero. But if I want to change the size of the picture (to make it bigger or smaller), changes are only made in one direction (from left to right and from top to buttom). I have used the function `gtk_widget_set_size_request(picture, width, height)`
Is there a possibility or a function, that I can use to make changes for example from right to left and from buttom to top? Thank you very much!

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)  would be helpful

Comment: @jku - Sorry what do you mean with SSCCE? Thanks :)

Comment: Click the link,  there's an explanation (it's Short Self Contained Compilable Example)